# Google Drive Authorization Returns Error 403 usageLimits on Android SDK<14

Tags: android, google-drive-api, google-api-java-client

I'm using Google Drive API in my Android app:

```
private Drive buildService(final GoogleCredential credentials) {

        return new Drive.Builder(AndroidHttp.newCompatibleTransport(), new GsonFactory(), credentials)
                .build();

    }
```

The credential is obtained using the accountManager. It works perfectly on Android 4.0 and above. I can get/insert/delete files etc. When running on Android 4.0 below, it always returns:

```
"error": {
  "errors": [
   {
    "domain": "usageLimits",
    "reason": "dailyLimitExceededUnreg",
    "message": "Daily Limit Exceeded. Please sign up",
    "extendedHelp": "https://code.google.com/apis/console"
   }
  ],
  "code": 403,
  "message": "Daily Limit Exceeded. Please sign up"
 }
}
```

Is this a compatibility issue? I'm using the lastest Drive api and google api lib(1.14.1). Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

You should enable "Google Drive API" on the API Console's services tab: https://code.google.com/apis/console/

Comment: I already did and the code works well on ICS. The 403 error occurs only on pre-ICS systems.

Comment: It should be at least working fine with 2.3.x. Are you still using the same certificate to sign the apk?